# How to use SQL tables as SharePoint lists?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server

We are creating a new SharePoint site for an existing application (.NET & SQL).

Now, we need to create few lists and use existing SQL tables as SharePoint lists. Is this possible, how to do it, any example??

Do I need import the data into SharePoint list by something like copy/paste in list worksheet mode (there are 76 tables, will take lot of time) or is there some other way in which I can link the list to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular approach is to use External Contenttypes with BCS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj163139.aspx

This enables you to use External Lists:

> **External lists**
>
> An external list enables access to data from external
>   systems in the same way that SharePoint list data is accessed.
>   External lists use external content types as their data sources.
>   External lists enable you to use the metadata that is already defined
>   about an external content type to create a SharePoint list that has
>   external data that looks and performs like any other SharePoint list.
>   You can also take external lists offline to be used in Outlook 2013.
>   This allows you to work with external data just like native Outlook
>   Item types, such as Contacts, Tasks, and Posts, and use the external
>   data in Office client applications. External lists enable writing back
>   to the external system if the external system allows it, and if it is
>   modeled accordingly by the external content type. This implies that
>   users can edit external data directly from within. Any changes that
>   were made to the items in the list are synchronized automatically with
>   the external system. Also by using the Refresh data button in the
>   list, you can synchronize and get updated data from the external
>   system automatically.

from above link.

This approach will keep a relationship between the SQL data and the list items.

For a full guide to create this from an SQL Source, follow this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj220063.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use Business Connectivity services to get data from SQL tables into SharePoint as lists. See this for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819133.aspx

Comment: OK, after implementing, say data is added or deleted from list, then, will it also get added/deleted from the SQL table as well?

Comment: Yes, you can perform CRUD operations using External lists